# Typo3 frontend-editing extension giving error as PHP Warning: Undefined array key "config."

Tags: typo3-extensions, typo3-11.x

I am trying to install Frontend-editing extension in Typo3 v11. After successful installation when I am trying to open the page in Frontend-extension in backend mode I am getting error like
PHP Warning: Undefined array key "config." in /git/httpdocs/website/public/typo3conf/ext/frontend_editing/Classes/Utility/ConfigurationUtility.php line 52

Steps used in installation are

1. composer req friendsoftypo3/frontend-editing
2. Include the extension in the template
3. Add the line in the Template setup
   config.tx_frontendediting = 1

Even after several trials I am getting the following error[Frontend-editing extension error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EblgM.png)

Strangely if I clear the cache this error is not shown, but on refresh this error pops up.
Anyone have faced such issues and could you resolve?

Answer (score 0):

After a long research found out the solution that I am jumping on the solution without adding any contents to the page. So the error was gone when some Content element was added.
Thanks for reading